# Sorting an array of hashes in Ruby (sorting by presence optional key+value)

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, sorting

Got a Ruby array like:

```
[  { "lat" => 123, "lon" => 456 },
   { "lat" => 789, "lon" => 102, "col" => "red" },
   { "lat" => 442, "lon" => 342 } ]
```

I would like to sort it so that **any** hash with `col` as a key will be pushed to the top or bottom of the array.

Can't figure out the right `sort_by` syntax/semantics.

Comment: Top or bottom; which?

Comment: What code have you written?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = [  { "lat" => 123, "lon" => 456 },
   { "lat" => 789, "lon" => 102, "col" => "red" },
   { "lat" => 442, "lon" => 342 } ]
```

If you want to put them on the top, then

```
a.partition{|h| h.key?("col")}.flatten
```

If you want to put them at the bottom, then as suggested by the Tin Man,

```
a.partition{|h| h.key?("col").!}.flatten
```

Comment: To put them at the bottom, try `!h.key?('col')` and remove `reverse`. They should accomplish the same thing but reduce the work.

Answer (score 1):

A more functional approach I like always:

```
require 'pp'

a = [ {:foo => "aa","col" => "bar"}, { "lat" => 123, "lon" => 456 },
   { "lat" => 789, "lon" => 102, "col" => "red" },
   { "lat" => 442, "lon" => 342 } ]

arr = a.group_by{|h| h.key?("col")}

pp arr[false] + arr[true] # on the bottom
```

***Output:***

```
[{"lat"=>123, "lon"=>456},
 {"lat"=>442, "lon"=>342},
 {:foo=>"aa", "col"=>"bar"},
 {"lat"=>789, "lon"=>102, "col"=>"red"}]
```

---

```
pp arr[true] + arr[false] #on the top
```

***Output:***

```
[{:foo=>"aa", "col"=>"bar"},
 {"lat"=>789, "lon"=>102, "col"=>"red"},
 {"lat"=>123, "lon"=>456},
 {"lat"=>442, "lon"=>342}]
```